# Android Studio emulator using proxy with username/password doesn't have access to Internet | Connection refused error

Tags: android-studio, proxy, android-emulator

I'm trying to use a 4G proxy with the Android Studio emulator.
The proxy connection is fine from the emulator settings.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMN3K.png)

But when I use the emulator, I can't go to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com), I get "Connection refused" from Chrome browser.
If I disable proxy in emulator parameters, Internet connection is OK.

If I add a new APN with my proxy settings, I can go to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) from browser, but other application still does not work. (My proxy needs username and password)

Have a nice day.
Regards.

If I disable proxy in emulator parameters, Internet connection is OK.

If I add a new APN with my proxy settings, I can go to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) from browser, but other application still does not work. (My proxy needs username and password)